# Sending Button Id to different Page

Tags: javascript, coldfusion-9, tinymce-4

For example I have different id's like temp1,temp2,temp3 etc for different buttons to uniquely identify 
them.

Is it possible to send the Id from one page (Page 1) to another Page 2, where(on Page 2) I have defined the following
code , considering that a button with temp1 is clicked by the user on Page 1.

```
<script>

var button = $.getUrlVars()['button'];

$("#temp1").click(function() {
    $("#sTinyMceEditorId").load("Folder/firsttemplate.html");
});
</script>

<script>
$("#temp2").click(function() {
    $("#sTinyMceEditorId").load("Folder/secondtemplate.html");
});
</script>

<script>
$("#temp3").click(function() {
    $("#sTinyMceEditorId").load("Folder/thirdtemplate.html");
});
</script>
```

The above code is defined on the Page 2. So, I am supposing that if somehow I can get the particular id transferred to Page 2 where the above code snippet is defined , then the corresponding script tag willbe initiated and the corresponding template will be loaded into the TinyMCeEditor (with the id sTinyMceEditorId)

I am wondering if this approach would work? Also, is the above way of defining separate script tags for each temp id's good?

Thanks

**Some Information if that helps in answering:**

Version of TinyMce I am using is 4.0.8 It's a ColdFusion 9 on which I am working on and inside Sessions. Perhaps this has nothing to do with my question above as all the stuff I think can be done using jQuery and java script.

Comment: Send it to Folder/firsttemplate.html?id=temp1 or use jQuery function http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: @estshy If I will send it to `Folder/firsttemplate.html?id=temp1` then it will end up in different page and not Page 2 where the editor is located. Could you elaborate why you mentioned this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the button id via a get parameter to the next page and then read it with jQuery.

**On Page 1** format your links like this

```
<a href="page2.html?button=temp1">Button 1</a>
```

**On Page 2**

```
var button = $.getUrlVars()['button'];
```

Which will store the value 'temp1' into the variable button

Or something similar to that.

**EDIT:**
I wrote the code for you below, but you're going to want to brush up on your JavaScript.

On Page 2

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var button = $.getUrlVars()['button'];

//these values should correspond to the values you are passing in your get parameters.
switch(button){
    case 'temp1':
        $("#sTinyMceEditorId").load("Folder/firsttemplate.html");
        break;
    case 'temp2':
        $("#sTinyMceEditorId").load("Folder/secondtemplate.html");
        break;
    case 'temp3':
        $("#sTinyMceEditorId").load("Folder/thirdtemplate.html");
        break;
    default:
        alert("Button id not recognized.");
        break;
}
</script>
```

**EDIT:** The getUrlVars function as an extension of jQuery - forgot to include.

```
    $.extend({
    getUrlVars: function(){
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++){
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[0]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return vars;
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks @isick , so on Page 1, the "button" word you have used , do I need to define it as a variable somewhere before I use it. Also, on Page 2 code that you have mentioned, I can use button in `$.getUrlVars()['button'];` and inside the script tag, am I right?

Comment: on page 1 you can replace the word "button" with whatever you like (no need to define it before hand). And on page 2 make sure the word inside the brackets and single quotes (in my case it says ['button']) matches the term you used on page 1. And yes, the code for Page 2 is JavaScript and belongs inside a script tag.

Comment: Thanks @isick, I have updated my script tag. Please have a look. Used exactly same variable like yours but it's not working for some reason.

Comment: See my edit above. I added the page 2 code for you. The cases in the switch statements should correspond to the get parameters you are setting in the respective button links.

Comment: I tried using `$("temp1")` instead of `$("#temp1")` inside script tag as I am getting temp1 on Page 2 but that didn't work either

Comment: You're changing the focus of your question. If you want to know how jQuery selectors work you should create a new question. In this thread you asked how to get data from one page to another.

Comment: Thanks for adding switch statements but for some reason the HTML is still not loading into the editor.  :(

Comment: Thanks, I'll create a new question.

Comment: I believe, we need to have getUrlVars() function before using `var button = $.getUrlVars()['button'];` something like mentioned here http://w3lessons.info/2013/02/25/how-to-get-url-parameters-values-using-jquery/

Comment: Good catch Jack. I've been extending jQuery so long I forgot which functions were native. I'll add an Edit.